# Laravel - Через некоторое время падает Homestead

Tags: php, linux, laravel, ubuntu, homestead

На рабочем компьютере всё нормально, на ноуте падает через некоторое время + тормозит (Homestead.yaml одинаковый естественно). По SSH (`vagrant ssh`) подключиться не могу после того как упал. Не знаю уже куда копать.

Linux (Ubuntu 20). Destroy пробовал — не помогло.

P. S. Открыл UI VirtualBox. Поправил ошибки, которые он высвечил:

- Graphics Controller установил в VMSVGA
- Добавил графической памяти на всякий случай
- Установил Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-6.1.18.vbox-extpack

Вроде бы стало лучше ...

[image: VirtualBox Settings]

Comment: Может ему оперативы не хватает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исправив указанные ошибки и добавив графической памяти, машина перестала падать.

Comment: крутая у вас машина: сама исправляет ошибки, сама добавляет графическую память… (это как бы тонкий намёк на классику «[Подъезжая к сией станцыи и глядя на природу в окно, у меня слетела шляпа](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Анаколуф)».