# Зависает виртуальная машина с Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, kali-linux, виртуализация

Запускаю на `Virtualbox` `Ubuntu` и `Kali`. Работает. Но если оставить виртуальную машину включенной и отойти (точное время не засекал, +- полчаса), то машина просто зависает с черным экраном.

- **Процессор:** `i5-9600KF, не разогнан`;
- **ОЗУ:** `16 ГБ`;
- **Диск, где стоит виртуалка:** `SSD Crucial MX500`;
- **Видеокарта:** `Radeon RX 570`;

---

**Под `Ubuntu`:**

- 1 ядро процессора из 6;
- 8 ГБ ОЗУ;
- виртуальный диск динамический, автоматически увеличивается до 500 ГБ;
- 16 МБ видеопамяти, 1 монитор;

**Под `Kali`:**

- 4 ядра процессора из 6
- 8 ГБ ОЗУ
- виртуальный диск динамический, автоматически увеличивается до 500 ГБ
- 64 МБ видеопамяти, 2 монитора

Еще заметил, что `Kali` при зависании жрет 60% процессора. На Ubuntu не проверял еще.

---

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема, куда копать, как решать? Дело в железе или настройки нужно менять? Или может нужно переходить с `VirtualBox` на `VMWare` или еще куда?

Comment: Там есть режим отключения экрана. Это точно зависло? Проверьте, доступен ли SSH, например. Какая хост-система? Вообще зависания могут быть, вот [тред](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=101448) у них на форуме.

Comment: Посмотри: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1248388/201026; может поможет.